# VBA Parsing XML contained in HTMLpage from IE Document

Tags: xml, vba, internet-explorer

I have a VBA program that uses IE Automation to query a web site a classical way:
    Const URL = "xxxx"
    Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
    Dim oHTMLDoc As HTMLDocument

```
ieApp.Navigate URL
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set oHTMLDoc = ieApp.Document
.....etc
```

For some reasons, I have to use the InternetExplorer object - I can't use MSXML2 library to query the site. Later in the program, the result of the query is pure XML - which is a pain to parse using HTML routines.

So my simple question: how can I transfer a HTMLDocument into an MSXML2.DOMDocument ?

```
Dim oXMLDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set oXMLDoc = oHTMLDoc  'Fails
```

Thank you.

Comment: If the query returns pure XML then you can use MSXML for that part...

Comment: Thanks Tim - I understand that but this is my question:how can I do that ? I need to use IE and oHTMLDoc to authenticate, how can I switch to MSXLM for further queries ? An Open/Send with XMLHTTP returns "not authenticated".

Comment: I'm unclear on the actual workflow here.  In normal operation via IE, what's the browser doing with something which is sent as pure XML?

Comment: I am accessing HP Agile Manager server. The recommendation to login is to use REST_API with XMLHTTP type of request - once you authenticate you receive pure XML to every query.Unfortunately I have not been successful to authenticate using the res_api (I know, that's the right way to do it...) so I am logging in using IE but then I am stuck when the reply is pure XML. Of course I can go through the HTML DOM...but that is not really practical. So my question. Hope this clarifies !

Comment: I think it might be less work to figure out how to authenticate against the REST API using MSXML than to continue using IE...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to jdweng I have the answer:

```
Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim oHTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim sXML as String 

ieApp.Navigate *URL*
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set oHTMLDoc = ieApp.Document
Set oXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

sXML = oHTMLDoc.DocumentElement.outerHTML
If Not oXML.LoadXML(sXML) Then _
    Err.Raise oXML.parseError.ErrorCode, , oXML.parseError.reason
```

And I can enjoy XML in my oXML document ! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'add reference Microsoft XML, v6.0
Public Sub DownloadFile()
    Dim objWHTTP As Object
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim arrData() As Byte
    Dim lngFreeFile As Long



    On Error Resume Next
        Set objWHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set objWHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    URL = "Enter URL Here"

    objWHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objWHTTP.send
    arrData = objWHTTP.responseBody
    strData = StrConv(arrData, vbUnicode)

    Dim fedbook As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    fedbook.LoadXML strData
​
```

Comment: Thank you jdweng. This does not work for me unfortunately. I must start with IE and oHTML document - I can't switch to the WinHTTP Get because I loose my authentification token. The question is how to get from a HTMLDocument to an XML document.

Comment: You need to look at source of webpage to determine what tags the XML is wrapped with.  Normally I go to webpage with an IE manually and then using menu select View : Source.  Or download the webpage to a file on computer and view file with text editor.  You can even look at the OutterXML in the download document.

Comment: Ok - that what it looks like:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
    -<Entities TotalResults="1557">
    -<Entity Type="release-backlog-item">
    -<Fields>
    <Field Name="no-of-sons"/> 
    <Field Name="release-id"/>
    -<Field Name="entity-type">
    <Value>requirement</Value>
    </Field>

Comment: Once you get the XML string like you have posted then you can use the LoadXML method like in my example.  I used strData as my string.  If you are getting bytes, then convert using StrConv like in my example.